# Switch haskell-process-type between cabal-repl and ghci

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

Can I switch the haskell-process-type on during an alive haskell session or when starting a new session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just type the following in a buffer and `C-x C-e` it afterwards (assuming `cabal-repl` is your default).

```
(setq haskell-process-type 'ghci)
```

In my `.emacs` I actually have this to make this easy, since I do this often:

```
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c h t") 
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (progn
      (setq haskell-process-type 'ghci)
      (message "Now in ghci mode."))))
```

Another `C-c C-l` will then load your interactive buffer with the correct mode.

**EDIT:** Using `haskell-mode-map` now.

Comment: Would `(define-key haskell-mode-map ...)` work aswell?

Comment: And should that be `C-x C-e` to evaluate?

Comment: You're right, I've made the correction. I'm not sure about `haskell-mode-map`.

Comment: Could you put an edit in the OP explaining what you did?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I extended fosskers answer a bit!

A function to toggle the process type:

```
(defvar haskell-process-use-ghci nil)

(defun haskell-process-toggle ()
  "Toggle GHCi process between cabal and ghci"
  (interactive)
  (if haskell-process-use-ghci
      (progn (setq haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl)
             (setq haskell-process-use-ghci nil)
             (message "Using cabal repl"))
    (progn (setq haskell-process-type 'ghci)
           (setq haskell-process-use-ghci t)
           (message "Using GHCi"))))
```

and a haskell-mode specific keybinding:

```
(define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-h C-t") 'haskell-process-toggle)
```

Comment: I agree now that `haskell-mode-map` is better to use. Also, instead of the `defvar`, you can just test directly on `haskell-process-type` like: `(if (equal 'ghci haskell-process-type) ...)`

Comment: I also use the variable in some other part of my config not included here, and it makes for nicer code I believe.